# Diamond diagram for Correspondence Theorem

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

This paragraph appears in Isaacs' *Algebra* (chapter on homomorphisms).

> We comment briefly on the interpretation of the Correspondence theorem in terms of lattice diagrams, at least in the case where $\phi$ is the canonical homomorphism $G\rightarrow G/N$. If we have a lattice diagram for some of the subgroups of $G$, including $N$, then the part of the diagram above $N$ is a valid lattice diagram for $G/N$. In fact, diamonds go over to diamonds, since if $N\subseteq U$ and $N\subseteq V$ and $UV$ is a group, then in $G/N$ we have $(U/N)(V/N)=(UV)/N$.

I get the last part that if $N\subseteq U$ and $N\subseteq V$ and $UV$ is a group, then in $G/N$ we have $(U/N)(V/N)=(UV)/N$, but I don't understand what he means in terms of the diagram and diamonds, and that diamonds go over to diamonds. Maybe this part of algebra is too "abstract" for me to understand...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the original diagram with $G$ at the top, the groups $UV,U,V$, and $N$ form a diamond with $UV$ at the top and $N$ at the bottom. The map $\varphi$ carries $UV$ to $(U/N)(V/N)$, $U$ to $U/N$, $V$ to $V/N$, and $U\cap V$ to $(U\cap V)/N$, which form a diamond in the lattice diagram for $G/N$. More generally, every diamond in the part of the $G$-lattice lying above $N$ is carried in similar fashion to a diamond in the $(G/N)$-lattice. Writing $W$ for $U\cap V$, we have this correspondence of diamonds:

```
                 UV                                 UV/N  
                /  \                                /  \  
               U    V                             U/N  V/N  
                \  /                                \  /  
                  W                                  W/N  
                  |                                   |  
                  N                                   1
```

Comment: Don't we need $N=U\cap V$ in order for $UV,U,V,N$ to form a diamond? I don't see that assumption anywhere.

Comment: @Paul: Yes; I meant to put that in and forgot when I decided to add the diagrams. Fixed now.

Comment: Thanks, very clear explanation. Not too "abstract" for me after all!

Comment: @Paul: You’re welcome!